# Linq query to get the most recently inserted Id from a table

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get the most recently inserted id from the TaskOrder table to use as a hidden field for when I create subtasks. My linq query is below and I am getting an anonymous type error that I can't figure out.

```
public async Task<int> GetLastTaskOrderId()
{
    var result = (from t in _context.TaskOrder
                  select new
                  {
                     TaskorderId = t.TaskOrderId
                  }).MaxAsync();

    return await result;
}
```

Comment: Change your last line to `return await result.TaskOrderId;`

Comment: This would cause a lot of trouble in concurrent environment.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Yes I would need to also filter by user ids as well I think

Comment: @RJC: filtering by user could help a bit but why don't you use your database to return newly inserted I'd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public async Task<int> GetLastTaskOrderId()
{
    var item = await _context.TaskOrder.OrderBy(u => u.TaskOrderId).LastOrDefaultAsync();
    return  item.TaskOrderId;
}
```

or

```
return  await _context.TaskOrder.MaxAsync(u => u.TaskOrderId);
```

I don't know which is faster since the prime key is usually indexed and clustered.